# onkeydown, and auto complete

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this issue or point me towards the right direction.

In my project we have a filed that needs to be autofilled, at this moment I use onblur which works wonders as it only does it so once you leave the focus. However, due to recent changes, it needs to only do so when there is only one unique item in the map which it matches the input.

I have a large array defined as following:

```
var myArray = [
[content, content],
[content, content],
...
]
```

Later in my code I associate it with a map, at least this is what most stackoverflow questions I looked at referred to it as follows:

```
var myMap = {};

for(0 to myArray.length) {
   var a = myArray[i][0];
   var b = myArray[i][1];

   myMap[a] = b; 

}
```

Now, finally I iterate over this array as follows:

```
for (var key in map) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (map[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(location.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
```

the above is the line of code I am struggling to figure out how to change. At this moment, while using on blur, if I type in the letter 'A' for example, and leave the focus area it will automatically fill it in with a certain name. However, in the array there are many other objects that begin with, or contain A. How can I change it so that the onkeydown event will keep going until it finally filters it down to to only possible key-value pair? I tried looking at MDN's documentation for filtering, but I do not think that will work for my purposes, or at least I am too inexperienced with JS.

Answer (score 0):

If the indexOf the first and last are nonnegative and equal, there is just one. You could do this with an && and boolean short circuit evaluation, but that will run very far right off the screen, so I am showing your code with one more nested if (up to you to add the end of the block). But we also need to see if there are matches on multiple keys.

```
var matchCount=0;
for (var key in map) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (map[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(location.toLowerCase()) >= 0){ 
if (map[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(location.toLowerCase()) == map[key].toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(location.toLowerCase())) {
matchCount++;
```

then outside your for loop:

```
if (matchCount==1){ //do your stuff
```

Comment: Quick edit, when you say nonnegative should that part be included in the if statement preceding the one you added?

Comment: no, you already checked it with your >=0. If they are equal, both are >=0

Comment: no problem. I was just covering the case where both were -1, but it was not like you had a unique answer, you just have no answer whichever side you start from.

Comment: Yeah, this sadly does not I suppose solve my issue. I do appreciate the help. So is there really any way to filter it down until only one unique answer? Perhaps getting size of the map or something like that?

Comment: I think the above should now work. You may need to think about whether if one key matches twice that is a problem (in which case leave the answer alone) or not (in which case ditch the innermost if).

Comment: Aye, that is what my other groupmate did so now it works. Ty for the helpful hints.